# evolution mail and exchange tls

Tags: email, evolution, exchange

Was informed this week Microsoft is about to lock down their exchange servers and allow tls1.2 only.
I run evolution for mail and it is currently working nice with Exchange online.
Does evolution mail support tls1.2 and anyone knows where I can check for it's settings?
Thanks.

Comment: My wireshark capture says.. Yes! Evolution supports TLS 1.2 ... `83 45.685957686 xx.xxx.xx.xx 192.168.2.137 TLSv1.2 135 Application Data`  ....... It's rather unclear from the application itself.  And it seems `evolution` does **not** use `openssl` libraries.  It seems to be built on `glib - gio` ... and the source tree seems to be vague in which versions of TLS are supported... but the field test says: **Yes, TLS 1.2 is supported**

Comment: I can confirm @RubberStamp investigation. A DPI tool showed tls1.2 between evolution and exchange online.